# What do we call the object in the relation of denotation?

Tags: semantics, theoretical-linguistics

If the relation between an object and the expression is denotation, is the object also called referent?

Comment: _An_ object? _The_ expression? _The_ object? Anarthrous _referent_? What context are you inhabiting?

Comment: If the denotation of an expression is an object/individual -- for instance, the denotation of the expression "the current president of the USA" is the individual Donald Trump -- then yes, this object is called the referent of the expression.